# Expression must be a modifiable lvalue C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

In C I can just store a string as an array, so I tried to do the following in C++:

```
message = "I am sending this back";
```

where message is defined in the following way:

```
#define mx 100
#define sizeArr (mx+1)
```

and in int main:

```
char message[sizeArr];
```

But I get the following error: "expression must be a modifiable lvalue."

What went wrong?

Comment: doing `char message[sizeArr];` and then `message = "I am sending this back";` even in C is very misleading and very likely not what you want.

Comment: You can't assign a string literal to an array of `char` in [either C or C++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37b2d23690b506c5).

Comment: Eeew, macros. Why not use proper (`const`) variables?

Comment: @JesperJuhl macros are not eeew in some cases.

Comment: @nicomp in 99+% of cases they are (IMHO) and here they certainly are.

Answer (score 3):

The following code is not what you want independent of language C or C++.

```
char message[100];
message = "abc";
```

You have to do something like this:

```
char message[100];
strcpy( message, "abc" );
```

P.S. In C++ there is a better solution, just use std::string:

```
string message;
message = "abc";
```

Comment: Since the OP tagged the post as C++, a better solution is to use `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

If you must use character arrays, here is a common idiom:

```
static const char my_text[] = "This is my text.";
```

A common idiom for the length, because it's compile time constant, is:

```
const size_t length_my_text = sizeof(my_text); // Includes terminating nul character.
```

For the length of the text without the terminating nul character:

```
const size_t length_no_nul = sizeof(my_text) - 1U;
```

For copying character arrays, see:   <s>`strcpy`, `strcat` and `strdup`</s> `strncpy`, and `strncat`.  See also `strlen`, and `strcmp`.

*The preferred C++ idiom for text is to use `std::string`*.

Comment: strcpy, strcat and strdup are not preferred either.

Comment: Using `std::string` is only preferred if you don't need that string at compile time.

Comment: The `std::string` is not preferred for memory constrained or safety situations where dynamic memory allocation is banned (due to fragmentation).